# EmptyIndexError - Index 'MAIN' does not exist in <whoosh.filedb.gae.DatastoreStorage object at 0x0667F130>

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, whoosh

I am testing out Whoosh on a project by following their quickstart guide:

http://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

The only difference is, my project is running off of Google App Engine, so instead of:

```
ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
```

I have:

```
from whoosh.filedb.gae import DatastoreStorage
ix = DatastoreStorage().create_index(schema)
```

And I get:

```
EmptyIndexError -  Index 'MAIN' does not exist in <whoosh.filedb.gae.DatastoreStorage object at 0x0667F130>
```

Comment: This error occurs when the index cannot be found--often, you create the index in one location and then whoosh looks for it in a different location. You can try specifying a discrete location that whoosh will use when building/reading the storage.